# BasicDataSource with JDBCTemplate not pooling connections as expected

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to use BasicDataSource to pool connections with JDBCTemplate in a spring application. From everything I've read, this should be really simple: Just configure the BasicDataSource in XML, inject the data source into a bean, and in the setter method, create a new JDBCTemplate.

When I did this, I noticed my performance was terrible. So then I switched to Spring's SingleConnectionDataSource, just to see what would happen, and my performance got *much* better.  I started investigating with a profiler tool, and I noticed that when using BasicDataSource, a new connection was being created for every query.

Investigating further, I can see where the connection is being closed after the query is finished. Specifically in Spring's DataSourceUtil class:

```
public static void doReleaseConnection(Connection con, DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    if (con == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (dataSource != null) {
        ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(dataSource);
        if (conHolder != null && connectionEquals(conHolder, con)) {
            // It's the transactional Connection: Don't close it.
            conHolder.released();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Leave the Connection open only if the DataSource is our
    // special SmartDataSoruce and it wants the Connection left open.
    if (!(dataSource instanceof SmartDataSource) || ((SmartDataSource) dataSource).shouldClose(con)) {
        logger.debug("Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

The thing that I notice is there is some special logic for 'SmartDataSource' which leaves the connection open. This partially explains the behavior I was seeing: Since SingleConnectionDataSource implements SmartDataSource, the connection is not closed.  However, I thought by using BasicDataSource, the close() method on the connection would just return the connection to the pool.  However, when I look at what is happening in my profiler, the close method is actually being called on my sybase connection: not any kind of 'Pooled Connection Wrapper' like I would expect to see.

One last thing (this is what I'm going to investigate now): I use TransactionTemplate for some of my queries (involving commits to the database), but simple queries are not inside a transactionTemplate.  I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem or not.

EDIT 1:

Ok finally got some more time to investigate after getting pulled off the project a bit and, here is a very simple test that shows the problem

```
    public class DBConnectionPoolTest {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.start();
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        template.queryForInt("select count(*) from mytable"); 
    }
    sw.stop();

    System.out.println("TIME: " + sw.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds");   
}}
```

Here are my two datasource configurations:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

When I run the test with the first configuration, it takes about 2.1 seconds. When I run it with the second configuration, it takes about 4.5 seconds.  I have tried various parameters on BasicDataSource, such as setting maxActive=1 and testOnBorrow=false, but nothing makes a difference.

Comment: Show us your config, around where you configure and inject the data source and the JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in my case was that my jdbc libraries for sybase were outdated.